# adwords tracking in analytics with autotagging

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have autotagging turned on, and I've verified that I can pass a gclid parameter, and it still appears on the url and is in the correct case on its way through. Is there any place I can see the gclid getting passed so I can verify that everything's ok on my end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer console on chrome to do this, check out: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2938246?hl=en